# Suddenly getting "403 Access not configured. Access Not Configured. Use Google Developers Console to activate the API" accessing Drive

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth

I have a long standing Drive/Appengine project ("Live") which is working.

I'm doing some upgrades to the Email interface, which means I need to create a second Appengine project ("Dev"), **using the same project ID**, to test email.

Up until an hour ago, both projects were working. Now I'm getting 403 errors when I try to access Drive from Javascript in Dev.

So the usual "go to cloud console and enable blah blah" doesn't apply. This was all enabled over a year ago and works fine for Live.

I've run the access token through the tokeninfo endpoint

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=ya29.1.AADtN_WIxVB6qhrUW0j7qdZwUcRIJyGGObG4ltsVymLQ-hqamjwCwCXE0Vqum
```

and I get

> {
>   "issued_to": "698624257.apps.googleusercontent.com", 
>   "audience": "698624257.apps.googleusercontent.com",  "user_id":
>   "1167149762340142",  "scope":
>   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
>   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.install
>   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me
>   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
>   ",  "expires_in": 2660,  "email":
>   "my.email@gmail.com",  "verified_email": true,  "access_type":
>   "offline" }

Which seems healthy enough.

Any suggestions?

A definitive list of the problems that can cause this error would be helpful.

**To repeat, (because I know somebody will suggest this answer) this app is WORKING for the majority of users and has Drive API and SDK enabled in the API Console**

Comment: are you getting authentication prompt popup ? while running app after Logged out

Comment: No. I'm getting what looks like a valid access token.

Comment: ok then you should make proper authentication get an access Token, i am posting the java-script code for this what i use for the auth, 
if this could help you

Comment: If the access_token you use recently obtained/refreshed? They can expire after a period of time. Also note that Google only grants upto 25 tokens and then expires the oldest one when you request a 26th

Comment: @Quango The access token is fresh. The 25 limit is for refresh tokens, of which I have only one. An expired refresh token would give an "invalid grant" exception, not "access not configured"

Comment: You have already covered that users can refuse to give the application access to their data? Even after they successfully ran through the auth.

Comment: @EdwinvanVliet yes. if the authorization had been withdrawn, I would have failed to receive an access token and got an "invalid grant" exception

Comment: are you using Canonical Extension Headers in your new requests?

Comment: @Messer no. exactly the same code is running on both appengine instances. I have also received sporadic reports from users who are seeing this error intermittently. I can't see any correlation between these errors and my code.

Comment: Is there one refresh token being used for all Drive access by the app, or one for each user?

Comment: @CraigCitro each user has their own refresh token